# Initializing 2D array in constructor

Tags: c++

Long story short I'm trying to initialize all the values of my 2D array to blanks in the constructor. I know I can create a for-loop to fill the array but I wanted to know if you could fill it using pointers or references which is what I think you have to do but I currently don't have the understanding to do such a thing.

```
class TicTacToe {

// state of the game
char M[3][3];
int numRemainingChoices; // number of remaining choices
char turn; // to determine whose turn it is

public:

TicTacToe(char array[][3]) {
// initializes each cell of M to a blank, sets turn to X, and 
numRemainingChoices to 9
M[][] = {{" ", " ", " "}, {" ", " ", " "}, {" ", " ", " "}};
turn = 'x';
numRemainingChoices = 9;
// Then calls runTicTacToe()
runTicTacToe();
}
```

Specifically, I want to fill the 2D array M with " " but I need to do so in the constructor. I tried adding the 2D array as a parameter and then filling it like I am in the code. When I try this I get an error stating: "excess elements in scalar initializer". I don't fully understand if this is just creating a copy of the array and filling that or if it would fill the original array with blanks. If someone could clarify and explain to me what's going on behind the scenes it would be a great help.

Comment: In C++11, use an extended initlialiser list.      But why are you using raw arrays rather then containers?   Standard containers are, among other things, easier to initialise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with `" "` is a *string* (which for practical purposes can be seen as a `char const*`), and you have arrays of `char`.

To continue that's not how you initialize an array, you can't assign to one.

Instead use an *constructor initializer list* like

```
TicTacToe()
    : M{{' ', ' ', ' ' }, {' ', ' ', ' ' }, {' ', ' ', ' ' }},
      numRemainingChoices(9), turn('x')
{
    // As little as possible here
    // ...
}
```

---

As noted by a comment, don't "run" anything in a constructor. A constructor should *initialize* the state of a new object, *only*. If you want to "run" anything, then do it once the object have been constructed:

```
TicTacToe gameObject;  // Create and initialize the object
gameObject.run();  // Start the game
```

Comment: And when he says "As little as possible" he most certainly means don't `runTicTacToe();`.

Comment: @user4581301 Indeed I do!

Comment: `" "` is not "essentially a `char *`".   It is a string literal, and it is represented as an zero-terminated array.   An array is not a pointer.

Comment: @Peter But as an array it naturally decays to a pointer to its first element. Reworded to make it clearer.